# Applying Chinese RemainderTheorem and Paillier Homomorphic encryption

Tags: paillier

I'm trying to optimize the decryption process for Paillier Homomorphic Encryption (PHE) using the Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT). However, I want to check if there's a different way of applying CRT to PHE apart from the traditional approach and still get the same result or a faster result since there's a simpler variant for the PHE as stated here in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem#Homomorphic_properties).

```
Recall that,      

=(^   ^2 ).   ,   = ^.^   ^2,   =()=(−1)(−1) 

=[((^ ^2 ))]^(−1) ,   =()^(−1)   = [(−1)(−1)]^(−1)  

                    =(^   ^2 ).    

                =(^((−1)(−1))   ^2 ). [[(−1)(−1)]^(−1)   ]  

                    =  [(^((−1))   ^2 ).(−1)^(−1)  ] 

                    =  [(^((−1))   ^2 ).(−1)^(−1)  ]  

Let = (−1)^(−1)         and       = (−1)^(−1)   

                    =  [(^((−1))   ^2 )]   

                    =  [(^((−1))   ^2 )]    



 = CRT(, )  

 =  [(^(−1)   ^2 )   ]  +  [(^(−1)   ^2 )   ]

  = (^   ^2 ).
```

Implementing the above steps in python gave me an inconsistent decryption result.

Is this proof correct, and if not, can anyone please explain as to why it's not correct and how to make it correct?

Comment: What if all of this correct and your implementation is incorrect?

Comment: Nine time out of ten the issue with implementing something like this is that the modular arithmetic is wrong. I'd double check that you are doing division and modular exponentiation correctly.

Comment: It's unclear what _Lp_ is in the question. Looking at the [wikipedia page as it was](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Paillier_cryptosystem&oldid=864449640#Semantic_security) when the question was asked does not help.

Comment: The method turns out to be correct and described more clearly in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/106605/555).